# Calculating $\langle Q^2\rangle$ for circuit with Johnson-Niquist noise

Tags: statistical-mechanics, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance

I have a problem from statistical mechanics which puzzles me as I never had a course in statistical mechanics.
So we have a series of a resistor and conductance and we assume that $Q/C=IR$ giving rise to the ODE
$$\frac{Q(t)}{C}=-\dot{Q(t)}R + \delta U(t)$$
where $\delta U(t)$ is the voltage fluctuation due to thermal noise. Moreover it satisfies:
$$\langle \delta Q(T) \rangle = 0, \hspace{0.2cm} \langle \delta Q(t) \delta Q(t') \rangle = \lambda \delta (t-t'). $$
I could already show that the solution is given by
$$Q(t)= e^{-\frac{t-t_0}{RC}} + \frac{1}{R} \int_{t_0}^t e^{\frac{1}{RC}(\tau - t)} \delta U(\tau) d \tau $$
using an integrating factor and that the variance is given by
$$\langle (Q(t)- \langle Q(t) \rangle)^2 \rangle = \frac{\lambda C}{2R}\left[1-\exp(\frac{2}{RC}(t_0-t)) \right].$$
Now my next task is to calculate $\langle Q^2 \rangle$ by using the hamiltonian $\mathcal{H}=\frac{Q^2}{2C}$ and this is the point where I don't know how to proceed (possibly to my lack of stat mech knowledge).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the goal is to calculate $\langle Q^2 \rangle$ using the canonical distribution
$$\langle Q^2 \rangle = \frac{\int dQ \,Q^2 e^{-\beta\mathcal{H}}}{\int dQ \,e^{-\beta\mathcal{H}}}=\frac{C}{\beta}.$$
These are just Gaussian integrals which are easy to evaluate and $\beta \equiv (k_B T)^{-1}$.

Probably the point of this exercise is to note that you get the same result in the limit $t\rightarrow \infty$ for your calculation of the variance if you set $\lambda= 2R/\beta$. And actually the expectation values for higher powers of $Q$ will agree too.